# discord.py ctx commands do not return anything

Tags: python, discord.py, ctx

I'm trying to use bot commands in discord so I can start using the bot prefix. I tried using ctx, but from the code that I have written, when I use .ping, it returns nothing. Anyone got any idea why?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in")       #login message

@bot.command(pass_context = True)    #trying to get "test" to return from .ping
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("test")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:         #testing the bot actually responds to something
        return
    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")

client.run('#bot token here')
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "return"? Also, in newer versions context is always passed, so `pass_context = True` is not necessary.

Comment: @kr8gz So, basically I just want the discord bot to send "test" when I use .ping

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong in your code:

1. Use `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot` not both
2. You didn't enable intents, so `message.author` is `None`, here's how:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable privileged intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

3. You're running the client, not the bot, if you want the commands to work run the bot and get rid of `client`
4. Change the decorator of the `on_message` and `on_ready` events and add `process_commands` at the end of `on_message`:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Here's your fixed code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= ".", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in")


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run('#bot token here')
```

Comment: One thing I would like to add is, (pass_context = True) is no longer used just for future purposes. Also, According to my knowledge, You are using the old resources of discord.py. I urge you to read the latest documentation.@IdotEXE

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your code that I have found.

1. Don’t use both `discord.Client()` and `commands.Bot()`
2. You need to enable intents. Go to the discord developers page then to your bot and enable both intents. [Quick Link To The Developer Page On Discord](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[image: Turn the intents on]

Then write this code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(commands_prefix=“.”, intents=intents)
```

Make sure you are not using any `client` here.

There are even more stuff needed to fix. Since now we are using bot, change everything saying client to bot. You also have to add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to the end of the `on_message` function. Also change `ctx.channel.send` to just `ctx.send`

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print("Logged in")       #login message

@bot.command(pass_context = True)    #trying to get "test" to return from .ping
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("test")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:         #testing the bot actually responds to something
        return
    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")

    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run('#bot token here')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use simple `ctx.send`, it's common for commands,

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")
```

Comment: that will change absolutely **nothing**

Comment: I've tried that, still doesn't do anything sadly